About the additive property of Donaldson's functional
Carlos Simpson gave a simple definition of Donaldson's functional in his paper. Let $P$ be the space of smooth Hermitian metrics over a complex vector bundle $E\to X$. For $K,H\in P$ and $H=Ke^{S}$ where $S$ is a self-adjoint endomorphism of $E$ with respect to either of metrics. For such pairs of metrics, he defines Donaldson's functional $\mathcal{M}$ as:
$$
\mathcal{M}(K,H)=\int_{X}\{\text{Some expression that involves the metrics K and S}\}
$$
Since the expression is not important for my question I omit it here. Donaldson's functional satisfies the following additive property
\begin{equation}\label{eq:additive}
\tag{$\star$}
\mathcal{M}(K,H)+\mathcal{M}(H,J)=\mathcal{M}(K,J)
\end{equation}
which in my opinion roughly says that this functional is a potential function on $P$. And Simpson claimed that to prove this property it suffices to show that
$$
\frac{\partial^{2}}{\partial t_{1}\partial t_{2}}\mathcal{M}(Ke^{t_{1}S_{1}},Ke^{t_{1}S_{1}}e^{t_{2}S_{2}})=\frac{\partial^{2}}{\partial t_{1}\partial t_{2}}\mathcal{M}(K,Ke^{t_{1}S_{1}}e^{t_{2}S_{2}})
$$ at $t_{1}=t_{2}=0$
and
$$
\frac{\partial^{2}}{\partial t^{2}}\mathcal{M}(K,Ke^{tS})=\frac{\partial^{2}}{\partial t\partial u}\mathcal{M}(Ke^{tS},Ke^{(t+u)S})
$$
at $t=1$, $u=0$.
I am confused as to why these two conditons are sufficient to show the additive property of Donaldson's functional. It seems too weak for me to prove the sufficency because the first condition is only required to hold at time $0$. And ignore the complex geometry background, I think it is just a problem of mathematical analysis. But I just don't know how to prove it. Here is some of my attempt:
$H=Ke^{S_{1}}$, $J=He^{S_{2}}$, then if we want \eqref{eq:additive} to hold it suffices to show that
\begin{equation}\label{eq:second_add}
\tag{$\star\star$}
\mathcal{M}(K,Ke^{t_{1}S_{1}})+\mathcal{M}(Ke^{t_{1}S_{1}},Ke^{t_{1}S_{1}}e^{t_{2}S_{2}})=\mathcal{M}(K,Ke^{t_{1}S_{1}}e^{t_{2}S_{2}})(**)
\end{equation}
holds at any time. Then we can regard \eqref{eq:second_add} as a function $g(t_{1},t_{2})$ and we only need to show that $g\equiv 0$. But we know that $g(0,0)=0$ and $\nabla g(0,0)=0$, hence it suffices to show that $D^{2}g\equiv 0$. But this condition is much stronger than the condition Simpson listed above. I don't have any more idea.

Could you add which of Simpson's papers you are reading? By the way, the argument in Donaldson's original paper is very clear, you might want to read that one as well.  (the one called "anti self-dual Yang-Mills connections over surfaces" or something similar)
